# Cant get page to redirect with Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, web, web-development-server

```
def add(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
        content = form.cleaned_data["content"]
        
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index",args=(title,content, {
      
        "entries": util.save_entry(title, content)
        })))
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/add.html",{
            "form": form
        })
else:
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/add.html",{
        "form": ContactForm()
    })
```

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

I cant seem to get the redirecting to work. Everything else works up till there please help. Below are my code and error

[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns9BZ.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYWvb.png)

[urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKOWv.png)

Comment: can you copy code inside "code tag" instead of images? pls

Comment: there are rules for asking questions and #1: don't attach image unless you have to

Comment: just fixed it. I didn't know I could do that. The error image is there also

Comment: Could you please show us your 'urls.py'?

Comment: just added urls

Comment: Make some effort when asking question. Code in the image is different from what you have pasted in the question. The error message is clear. You provided content and entries in the arguments for the reverse(), now check your urls, do you see any url there that accepts content and entries arguments?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: idk that is why I am asking for help